# Install zbar failed on Watson Studio

Tags: watson-studio

I tried to execute this

```
    ! pip install zbar
```

The error message is

```
 Collecting zbar
  Using cached .../zbar-0.10.tar.bz2
Building wheels for collected packages: zbar
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for zbar ... error
  Complete output from command /...:
  ...
  gcc ...
  In file included from zbarmodule.c:24:0:
  zbarmodule.h:26:18: fatal error: zbar.h: No such file or directory
   #include <zbar.h>
                    ^
  compilation terminated.
```

Looks like an include file is missing. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, it does need zbar-devel to be installed on centos kind systems.

```
sudo yum install zbar-devel
```

Sudo is disabled on Jupyter Notebook on watson studio and is only accessible
by Watson Studio - IBM Cloud Operators.
At this moment, it is advisable to raise the Enhancement request so that
Watson studio Development team can consider and install this library by default.
http://ibm.biz/dsxideas

Thanks,
Charles.